# PhpStorm doesn't show some folders in Linux

Tags: php, linux, phpstorm, parrot-os

I have my PHP installed in form of LAMPP in my `/opt/lampp` folder. The problem is that PhpStorm is unable to see `/opt` folder and that's why I am unable to set PHP interpreter in PhpStorm.

Does anyone knows what the issue might be? I have pasted a picture as well showing the folder structure in file explorer as well as in PhpStorm.

Just to let you know that I have installed PhpStorm from **flatpak**...

[image]

Comment: This has to be Flatpack-related issue. Flatpack means sandboxing; not all paths/tools will be reachable/allowed. It might be similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586778/why-is-phpstorm-flatpak-unable-to-access-var-www

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I ended up removing the flatpack version and installing the official one. I used the tutorial from the official JetBrains page (see below), installed toolbox first, and then phpstorm from the toolbox, and that version had all the folders available.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/installation-guide.html#toolbox

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34651198)